# Dynamic table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to create a dynamic table with PHP. Number of rows will be based on the number of records pulled from mysql but I only want 4 rows in a line. Here is what I have right now

```
$sql = "SELECT t.tankid,t.TankName,tc.paramid,tc.active,pr.paramname,pr.minvalue,pr.maxvalue,pr.incvalue,pr.value from mr_tanks t inner join mr_testconfig tc ON tc.tankid = t.tankid inner join mr_parameters pr ON tc.paramid = pr.parameterid where t.tankid = :tankid and t.active = 1 and tc.active = 1";
$records1 = $con->prepare($sql);
$records1->bindParam(':tankid', $_GET['tankid']);
$records1->execute();
$headers = $col = "";
while ($row1 = $records1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $headers .= "<th> {$row1['paramname']} </th>";
    $col .= "<td> {$row1['minvalue']} </td>";
}
echo "<table><tr>$headers</tr><tr>$col</tr></table>";
?>
```

What I'm getting is all the rows are in line like this:

> Header 1  Header 2    Header 3    Header 4 Header 5   Header 6    Header 7    Header 8
>     Data 1         Data 2     Data 3      Data 4
>     Data 5         Data 6     Data 7      Data 8

And I would like it to be

> Header 1   Header 2    Header 3    Header 4
>   Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4
>   Header 5   Header 6    Header 7    Header 8
>   Data 5  Data 6  Data 7  Data 8
>   Hole

```
    _____________________________________________________________
    |  TestName 1  |  TestName 2  |  TestName 3  |  TestName 4  |
    |___________________________________________________________|
    |  ResultTest1 |  ResultTest2 | ResultTest3   | ResultTest 4|
    _____________________________________________________________
    |  TestName 5  |  TestName 6  |  TestName 7   |  TestName 8 |
    |___________________________________________________________|
    |  ResultTest5 |  ResultTest6 | ResultTest7  | ResultTest 8 |        

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> TestName 1</th>
        <th> TestName 2</th>
        <th> TestName 3</th>
        <th> TestName 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> ResultTest 1</td>
        <td> ResultTest 2</td>
        <td> ResultTest 3</td>
        <td> ResultTest 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> TestName 5</th>
        <th> TestName 6</th>
        <th> TestName 7</th>
        <th> TestName 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> ResultTest 5</td>
        <td> ResultTest 6</td>
        <td> ResultTest 7</td>
        <td> ResultTest 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It means two tables, isn't it ?

Comment: You need two tables?

Comment: this is 1 table. In header is a Name of the test and in data will be a result.

Comment: but based on your expected outcome it seems that you want to split after each four name

Comment: I updated a question I put a scratch of the table hope it will give you better idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Number of test can go anywhere from 1 to 16. I just want 4 test and they results in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chunk rows into a 2 dimensional array and then loop through them, where each chunk would give you a separate table with 4 rows in each.

If last chunk has less then 4 rows you can decide to leave the table with fewer than 4 columns, or if you still need it to be 4 columns then add filler rows with empty paramname/minvalue.

```
$results = array();
while ($row1 = $records1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $results[] = $row1;
}

$results = array_chunk($results, 4);
foreach($results as $chunk) {
  $headers = "";
  $col = "";
  foreach($chunk as $row) {
    $headers .= "<th> {$row)['paramname']} </th>";
    $col .= "<td> {$row)['minvalue']} </td>";
  }
  echo "<table><tr>$headers</tr><tr>$col</tr></table>";
}
```